# Backup command changing file types in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, backup

Im going through a directory and copying the images with the file extensions shown to a new folder. However some of the images have the same name so i'm using the backup command.

The trouble i'm having when it renames and copies is that the file type changes from an image to the recycle logo (im not sure what it means).

Also is it possible to have the file 'image_2101.JPG' renamed to 'image_2101.JPG.JPG' instead of just putting .~1~ when its copied

```
find /root/folder/images \( -name  '*.png' -o  -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.JPG' \) -exec cp --backup=numbered -t/root/folder/CopiedImages {} +
```

Comment: By the way, you could use ```-iname '*.jpg'``` to do a case-insensitive test. It will match `*.jpg`, `*.JPG`, `*.Jpg`, `*.jPG`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

`cp --backup` assings the backup extension `~` to the files and the `numbered` option makes it to use `~1~`, `~2~` and so on, so in order to change it you must create a script to change the behaviour.

This script would create a copy of every image under `sourcefolder` to a single folder destination (would **not** create any subdirectory), avoiding collisions by appending a number to the file, just before the extension.
Note that every time it is run, it will duplicate every file, just as your script does.
The `while IFS` part is needed for filenames with spaces.

```
sourcefolder="/root/folder/images"
destinationfolder="/root/folder/CopiedImages"
find "${sourcefolder}" \( -name  '*.png' -o  -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.JPG' \) -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' img; do
    imgname="${img##*/}"
    ext="${imgname##*.}"
    noext="${imgname%.*}"
    destname="${destinationfolder}/${noext}.${ext}"
    count=0
    while [ -f "${destname}" ] ; do
        count=$((count+1))
        destname="${destinationfolder}/${noext}.${count}.${ext}"
    done
    cp "${img}" "${destname}"
done
```